# How to change UINavigationController Title & backButton programming?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have two viewControllers.

vc1 -> presentVC -> vc2

vc2 inherit UINavigationController

I want to set title & backButton in vc2,but it doesn't work.

```
class vc2: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set title!!!
    //self.navigationItem.title = "123"
    //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "123"
    //self.title = "123"
    //self.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "123"
    //self.navigationItem.title = "123"

    // set backButton!!!
    let navButtonWidth:CGFloat = 44
    let backButton:UIButton = UIButton()
    backButton.setImage(backImage, for: .normal)
    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(back), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)]

}
```

Comment: What does not work button not adding on navigation bar or not performing action?

Comment: how to make it work?

Comment: You want to go on previous controller on button click?

Comment: CHECK THIS-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230261/jsqmessageview-controller-add-back-button-image-on-navigation-bar-swift

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154237/how-to-set-the-title-of-a-navigation-bar-programatically) (title) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230261/jsqmessageview-controller-add-back-button-image-on-navigation-bar-swift) (back button) out.
Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the code below in **perform(segue)** or **viewWillDissappear** depended on how do you do your presentation - via Storyboard segue or manually from code.

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem()
backButton.title = "whatever_you_want"
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

And in **viewDidLoad** of your `vc2` simply put

```
navigationItem.title = "Controller title"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can change it in storyboard Or change it in code.

I usually do this.

First hide navigation bar from default navigation controller.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
```

Create navigation bar in storyboard and outlet it.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!
```

Create custom navigation item.

```
private lazy var customNavigationItem: UINavigationItem = {
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "cancel_icon"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelTapped))

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    navigationItem.title = "Your Title"

    return navigationItem
}()
```

Add custom navigation item to navigation bar

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
    navigationBar.setItems([customNavigationItem], animated: false)
}
```

Hope it help.